# Preserving <br> tags when parsing HTML text content

Tags: php, dom, xpath, html-parsing

I have a little issue.
I want to parse a simple HTML Document in PHP.
Here is the simple HTML :

```
<html>
       <body>
             <table>
                     <tr>
                          <td>Colombo <br> Coucou</td> 
                          <td>30</td>
                          <td>Sunny</td> 
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                          <td>Hambantota</td> 
                          <td>33</td>
                          <td>Sunny</td> 
                     </tr>

             </table>    
       </body>
 </html>
```

And this is my PHP code :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$html = $dom->loadHTMLFile("test.html");

$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table'); 


$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr'); 


foreach ($rows as $row) 
{ 

  $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td'); 

  echo $cols->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
  echo $cols->item(1)->nodeValue.'<br />'; 
  echo $cols->item(2)->nodeValue;
}
```

But as you can see, I have a `<br>` tag and I need it, but when my PHP code runs, it removes this tag.
Can anybody explain me how I can keep it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to capture the values of the table cells with help of XPath:

```
$values = array();

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach($xpath->query('//tr') as $row) {
   $row_values = array();

   foreach($xpath->query('td', $row) as $cell) {
      $row_values[] = innerHTML($cell);
   }

   $values[] = $row_values;
}
```

Also, I've had the same problem as you with `<br>` tags being stripped out of fetched content for the reason that they themselves are considered empty nodes; unfortunately they're not automatically replaced with a newline character (`\n`);

So what I've done is designed my own innerHTML function that has proved invaluable in many projects. Here I share it with you:

```
function innerHTML(DOMElement $element, $trim = true, $decode = true) {
   $innerHTML = '';

   foreach ($element->childNodes as $node) {
      $temp_container = new DOMDocument();
      $temp_container->appendChild($temp_container->importNode($node, true));

      $innerHTML .= ($trim ? trim($temp_container->saveHTML()) : $temp_container->saveHTML());
   }

   return ($decode ? html_entity_decode($innerHTML) : $innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: First thank you for your interest and for your code.
I have a error with your code :
"Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to innerHTML() must be an instance of DOMElement,..."
I have probably a bad use of your code, i tried this :
`$dom = new DOMDocument();
   $dom->loadHTMLFile("test.html");
  
   $values = array();

   $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

   foreach($xpath->query('//tr') as $row) {
      $row_values = array();

      foreach($xpath->query('//tr') as $cell) {
         $row_values[] = innerHTML($cell->nodeValue);
      
      }

      $values[] = $row_values;
   }`

Comment: Made a correction to the code, the inner query was wrong, sorry =)

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not really comfortable with this, but I still have this error. :(

Comment: Aaaaw thank you very much !I did a mistake, it's working now !