# innerText is concatenating words

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So HTML.outerHTML outputs `<td><p><b>Ranges of</b><br><b>Exercise</b> <b>Prices</b></p></td>`

HTML.innerText outputs "Ranges ofExercise Prices"

HTML is an HTMLElement

The result I'm trying to get is "Ranges of Exercise Prices". innerText and textContent both give the same incorect result. How can I prevent the concatenation of strings with those line break tags present? (Can't change the HTML)

Comment: text does not have html in it.... so I am unsure how you are matching HTML to text. What you want to do is going to have to be a bit more involved since there is no DOM method to know is there is a line break with a tag.

Comment: What is the exact HTML mark up you are trying to read?

Comment: @epascarello <p><b>Ranges of</b><br><b>Exercise</b> <b>Prices</b></p>

Comment: I am not matching html to text, I was just trying to show the result of outerText and innerText

Comment: There is no whitespace between the tags so you are trying to get it to get the <br> tag to be a whitespace.

Comment: Yes, if that is possible that would work

Comment: Have a look at this...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938286/preserving-br-tags-when-parsing-html-text-content

Comment: @dev This is relating to PHP, I'm not sure it applies to my question

Answer (score 0):

This is a whack a mole way, but you can replace the br element with a space so it will show up as a space when you replace it.

```js
const temp = document.querySelector('.test').innerHTML;
const cloned = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(temp, 'text/html');
 cloned.documentElement.querySelectorAll('br').forEach(function (br) {
   br.replaceWith(' ');
});
console.log(cloned.body.textContent);
```

```html
<div class="test"><p><b>Ranges of</b><br><b>Exercise</b> <b>Prices</b></p></div>
```

Comment: br.replaceWith(' '); is causing build issues. I get the unhelpful error "npm run-script build exited with code 2" (I always get this when it fails to build). The only difference with my code is I use HTML.outerHTML to set temp instead of document.querySelector('.test').innerHTML. Does this difference matter?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getTextContent() {
  alert(document.getElementById("demo").textContent)
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"><b>Ranges of </b><br><b>Exercise</b> <b>Prices</b></p>
<button onclick="getTextContent()">Get textContent</button>
```

You can use `textContent` to get only text inside the `p` tag

Comment: You added a space after `of` which is the whole point of the question.

Comment: @pilchard yes. If not adding space it will appear as `Ranges ofExercise Prices`

Comment: Precisely, that is the OPs question. Without changing the HTML extract the text with the appropriate space between 'of' and 'Exercise'. (which is currently a <br> element).

Comment: Ok.. I think `<br>` not convert into space.

Comment: Correct, I can't change the HTML